# How can I retrieve the Lifetime sales of the stores programatically

Tags: magento

If there any particular column in tables where Magento stores this data? For example if i want to fetch the data from somewhere else. By running raw php mysql queries.
Not using Magento layer.

I know there is a function getTotal(). But hope you understand what I am trying to say.
Is there any way other than creating own custom API?
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `sales_flat_order` table. Specifically, if you want the sum of all sales taken by your store:

```sql
SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM sales_flat_order WHERE is_active = 1;
```